# Possible run MacOS on Hyper-V without nested virtualization?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Now i develop Xamarin application on my Hyper-V workstation. I'm using nested virtualization to host MacOS Mojave on Ubuntu host.

I write small project describe this https://github.com/vkorotenko/MacOSMojaveOnHyper-V

But i have some problem. To many virtualization and no HW accelerated video. 
Possible or not run MacOS on Hyper-V with hardware video acceleration without nested virtualization?

Answer (score 0):

I searched several forums and it seems that it is not supported by Apple. Thus, there is some instable projects to do so.

You may search for images on Google, but it is far easier to find stable versions for VMWare and VirtualBox. The reason is that HyperV is a closer to metal virtualization that is specific to Microsoft and harder to deploy for hackers than a classical virtual machine.

I understand that you may want to use HyperV since many other dev tools requires it. Docker and WSL are good examples.

Another option is to rely on Hackintosh to install your MacOS on bar metal, by making a partition of your disk. This will be the closest to native performances and behavior.

All of this is NOT supported by Apple EULA and thus I will not provide any link. But it is easy to find.